# Update RectChart JS Options on Button Click

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

Trying to update React Chart JS options on button click using Chart.update() method. But its not working. Here is the code

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Chart } from "chart.js";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import { Scatter } from "react-chartjs-2";

import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

const EventChart = ({ sId }) => {

function handleValueChkChange() {
    Chart.options.plugins.datalabels.display= false;
    Chart.update();
  }

 return (
<Grid item xs={12}>


<FormGroup>
            <FormControlLabel
              onChange={handleValueChkChange}
              control={<Checkbox />}
              label="Values"
            />
          </FormGroup>
            {chartData && (
              <Scatter
                style={{ width: "70%", height: "70%" }}
                data={chartData}
                options={options}
              />
            )}
          </Grid>
  );
};

export default EventChart;
```

**ERROR:**

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plugins')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plugins')
    at handleValueChkChange (https://localhost:3000/main.d9e9b2f82ffc9a60a64e.hot-update.js:192:57)
    at handleInputChange (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:125996:7)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:216096:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:216140:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:216197:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:216211:29)
    at executeDispatch (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:220355:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:220381:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:220392:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:220401:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleValueChkChange() {
    chart.options.plugins.datalabels.display= false;
    Chart.update();
  }
```

In your code, chart.option is camelCase And your Chart object is PascalCase?

You can define options as react state, and update state on demand after that call update method.

---

I implemented a example code for your problem and its will be work:
[Sample Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-almeida-ec4fi2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: sorry it was a typo in question, now updated with error

Comment: Ok i guessed. Register chart is ok and no problem, for the change options use state is recommended.

Comment: You can use the useRef in react to access to scatter chart like thid:

Comment: ```import { useRef } from 'react';
import { Bar, getDatasetAtEvent } from 'react-chartjs-2';

function App() {
  const chartRef = useRef();
  const onClick = (event) => {
    console.log(getDatasetAtEvent(chartRef.current, event));
  }

  return (
    <Bar
      ref={chartRef}
      data={data}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}```

Comment: Updated: Scatter
                ref={chartReference} ---chartReference.current.config.options.plugins.datalabels.display = false;
    chartReference.Update();   -- but  it says chartReference.Update is not a function, is there something i am missing?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-almeida-ec4fi2